# Skip check table import?

Tags: mysql, sql

When importing a file, I check the file, read all the lines, after which the import itself takes place.
I imported a 2 GB file (2 hours of import), and then another 2 GB file (import has already been 4 hours).
How to import:

```
UPLOAD A LOCAL DATA FILE "E:\\2.txt " To THE User TABLE
FIELDS ENDING WITH THE SYMBOL ':'
LINES ENDING WITH THE CHARACTER '\n'
(`username', `password');
```

What to do?

Comment: What checks are you doing and where?

Comment: When importing the same file again, the import takes twice as long

Comment: Why not truncate the table between loads.

Comment: What is your "how to import" command? It's nothing MySQL will execute, is it for some script, or is it a paraphrase of your actual command? Also, paraphrasing P.Salmon: if you are asking how to "Skip check table import?" of checks you do yourself ("I check the file, read all the lines"), you need to tell us "What checks are you doing and where?".

Comment: When importing the same file, the waiting time is twice as long (compared to the first one. although the file is the same)
Use OpenServer. Console

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
--- setup parameters
set sql_log_bin=OFF;//turn off logging
set autocommit=0;//turn off autocommit mode
set names utf8;

use database name;

--- Open transaction
START TRANSACTION;

--- Introduce the SQL file
--- path to source file

--- Commit the transaction after success 
COMMIT;
```

First export the table build statement and data statement separately, then build the table manually, remove foreign keys and indexes, and then import the data so that it will be very fast.